# How to set values for cards in a card deck and compare which one has "higher" or "lower" value?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, enums, compare, key-value

How to compare card values or even store them ?

I'm pulling data from an API that gives me 1 card - and then I want to compare their values to see which one is higher with the next card.. how can I do something like that ?

My values are pulled from an API and they return 'K' for King, or '5' for 5, 'A' for Ace and so on.. but I'm not sure how could I compare values of different types together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary.

```js
var cards = {
 'A' = 14, // Ace
 'K' = 13  // King
}
```

Or you can use an enum like object:

```js
const Cards = {
  A: 14, // Ace
  K: 13  // King
};
```

Comment: makes sense, and then compare
```if (cardOne > cardTwo) {] 
else { cardOne < cardTwo } 
else equal```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Card`-class and make it either `Comparable` more write a `Comparator<Card>`